# Summing elements in sliding window after applying function to last n elements

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I currently have a dataframe formatted as such:

```
 a b c e f
 2 3 4 5 1
 9 8 6 4 6
 1 2 2 2 3
 9 8 8 9 1
 3 6 8 6 2
 . . . . . 
 . . . . . 
 7 5 4 1 8
```

My goal is to apply an adaptive weight function over the last n(4) games in a sliding window. On each individual column.
For example:

```
awa = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4])
col a 
a5 = sum([2, 9, 1, 9] * awa)
```

So the 5th element would be equal to the sum of last 4 (.2 + 1.8 + .3 + 3.6) = **5.9**
I want to do this while maintaining the original dataset - meaning the 5.9 calculation wouldn't be used in the AWA calculation for the next elements.
Next calculation:

```
a6 = sum([9, 1, 9, 3] * awa)
a6 = 5
```

And so forth...

My initial approach would be the following:

1. Convert the dataframe to a numpy array

```
df.to_numpy()
```

2. Utilize the np.convolve function OR sliding window view

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view
np.sum(sliding_window_view(values, window_shape = 4), axis = 1)
np.convolve(mydata,np.ones(4,dtype=int),'valid')
```

My problem becomes twofold:

1. How do utilize these functions on columns instead of numpy rows?
2. How to apply the adaptive weight function dynamically to each 'column slice' before remaking the frame?

Comment: Would `.rolling` help at all? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html Perhaps: `df.rolling(4).apply(lambda x: x @ awa)`

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs I was about to suggest it, you should post it as answer ;)

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs Where would rolling store the values? Would it incorporate the adaptive weight average(s) in the next calculation?

Comment: As far as I know, rolling does not store any values, it returns you a Rolling object which, when prompted for some calculation (`.sum`, `.mean`, `.apply` etc.), computes the boundaries of each window on the fly, and passes the subframes to the aggregator. You can for instance create your own Indexer (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/window.html#custom-window-rolling) that computes the rolling window boundaries. That said, I am not an expert on pandas internals, so you'd have to dig in the code to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/window.html). For example something along these lines:

```
df['a_r'] = df['a'].rolling(4).agg(lambda x: x@awa)
```